# How to use pandas to read csv inside local package module?

Tags: python, pandas, module

I created a python module with a lot of custom functions that I use for various tasks of my work. Inside the module I want to be able to read a local CSV file.

```
import pandas as pd

def my_function():
    print('Hello World')
    df = pd.read_csv('spreadsheet.csv') #This file is in the same folder as the module.
    return df
```

I import my module in jupyter notebook to try to use it as so:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Users/me/Documents/mymodule')
import mymodule

my_module.my_function()
```

But I will get the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'spreadsheet.csv'` since it is trying to read it from the folder with my jupyter noteobok instead of the module folder.

Comment: Provide the proper path of CSV file. Currently pandas is not able to look at right directory for CSV file.

Comment: You may want to look into using python's built in pathlib module. If you use Path(__file__) and create a relative path to the CSV that you're reading from your module, the code will always have the correct path for the CSV regardless of the working directory

Answer (score 0):

`PATH` is for finding commands not synonymous with *working directory*.  Far better to adopt pass the file to be opened to you function.  Also for testing purpose you see I've made use of `if __name__ == '__main__':` pattern

#### my module

```
import pandas as pd

def my_function(path):
    return pd.read_csv(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pathlib import Path
    print(my_function(Path().home().joinpath("PyCharmProjects/sensorvenv/jupyter/a.csv")))
```

#### jupyter

```
from pathlib import Path
import mymodule
mymodule.my_function(Path().cwd().joinpath("a.csv"))
```